# DateTime Python

Tags: python, datetime, date

How to convert "12/17/2010 4:12:12 PM" to a datetime object?

For eg, If it was like "2007-03-04T21:08:12Z", I would have done

```
dd =datetime.strptime( "2007-03-04T21:08:12Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" )
```

but for time with AM/PM is there any direct way of doing?

Comment: The solution is ..
dd =datetime.strptime( "2007-03-04T12:08:12AM", "%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%p" )
Thanks @Ignacio

Comment: A better solution is to search for the previous answer to an identical question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `strptime(3)` man page:

```
   %I     The hour on a 12-hour clock (1-12).

 ...

   %p     The locale’s equivalent of AM or PM.  (Note: there may be none.)
```

Comment: that does not help because, I get this output

>>> datetime.strptime("12/17/2010 4:12:12 PM","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 17, 4, 12, 12)
>>> datetime.strptime("12/17/2010 4:12:12 AM","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 17, 4, 12, 12)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below to handle "AM" or "PM" in a date

%I refers 12-hour format

%H refers 24-hours format

t = "12/17/2010 4:12:12 PM"
res = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
print res
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 17, 16, 12, 12)

%p - refers am/AM/pm/PM.

Answer (score 0):

d1= '12/17/2010 4:12:12 PM'

fmt = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'

d2=datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, fmt)